# How to replace Smart Image with a different graphic WITHOUT using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photoshop-scripting, javascript, script

[This Q&A](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92796/replacing-a-smart-object-in-bulk-with-photoshops-variable-data-or-scripts/93359) offers a method by using Photoshop to load .js. However, I found [this website](https://flamingtext.com/logo/Design-Fire) can achieve this goal without using Photoshop.

My question is how this website achieves this goal?

Comment: Hello @olivia and welcome to GDSE, I don't think they goes with photoshop smart object. the one they using should probably achieved by some sort of styling code which can be dynamic! So I don't think it has to be any connection with photoshop :D

Comment: Olivia, I think a better example mIght be https://placeit.net/iphone-mockup-templates

Comment: @Mr.Online Hi Thanks. Maybe, we can still use Photoshop, but we should avoid open Photoshop and install script. Instead, we can directly use Photoshop library.

Comment: This won't be possible with JavaScript: JS scripts require Photoshop. But might be with Python and `psd-tools`: https://pypi.org/project/psd-tools/ I haven't tried myself though.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clear: if your question is about Photoshop, you already have the answer. If it's about the website (which has nothing to do with smart objects) then you're asking about web implementation which is off-topic here, better check on [so].