# Automating replacing a smart object in a mock up, then adding a texture map over the image

Tags: photoshop-scripting, smartobject, mockup

I'm an artist using Photoshop to create mock-ups of my art on multiple products.

I've been following this [thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92796/replacing-a-smart-object-in-bulk-with-photoshops-variable-data-or-scripts/93359) and used it on a number of mock-ups to replace the image I'm adding to a product, for example, a mug.

I have found that the script works perfectly with simple mock-ups, however when I try to use a T-shirt mock-up that has additional steps in the creation the automation asks for my input.

When saving the smart object, I'm asked to OK the displacement map settings. Once I approve the settings I have to locate and select the displacement file for the mock-up. After I have done this the script continues onto the next file, and so on.

I could sit and do the keystrokes, though I'm sure the script could be tweaked to add these extra steps.

Comment: If you have no experience with PS scripting you will have a hard time adjusting the script. It is possible but it probably will take you longer to figure this out that the time it will save you.

Comment: I have a vague idea about JS and I'm willing to try!